# FETCH PATCH request returns my data as being null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

```js
app.patch('/api/todos/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await pool.query("UPDATE todolist SET task = $1 WHERE id = $2;", [req.body.task, req.params.id])
        res.json(req.body)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
    }
})
```

I am trying to make a fetch PATCH request, but every time I do, instead of grabbing the value from the alert window and storing its value in my database, it returns null, or an empty string.  Not sure why it is doing this, because it works perfectly well on Postman.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```js
import React from "react";

class UpdateBtn extends React.Component {
    
    render() {


        const updateTodo = (e, alert) => {
            fetch('api/todos/' + e, {
              method: 'PATCH',
              header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({ task: alert })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => console.error(error.message))
          }

        const handleUpdate = (e) => {
            const alert = window.prompt("Update Task:")
            if (alert.length === 0) {
                return undefined;
            }
            updateTodo(e.target.id, alert)
            // window.location.reload()
        }

        return (
            <button 
            className="updateBtn"
            id={this.props.id}
            value={this.props.value}
            onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
        )
    }
}

export default UpdateBtn;
```

Comment: If it's working with Postman, it might be a header issue.